# course of something (verb+ing)

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure, verb-forms

I read a sentence:

> I completed course of creating blue jacket conducted by M.S.

Now, I do not know whether I can use 'course' (meaning classes) with '**of**' and **'verb+ing'** pattern. I know that I should use it before noun like 'make up course' etc, but it doesn't sound proper to me.

Please clarify my doubts regarding structure of this sentence. Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you would explain a bit more about what you would like this sentence to say.

Answer (score 1):

Consider rearranging the words, something like this:

> I completed the 'creating blue jacket' course, which was conducted by M.S.

or

> I completed the course on creating a blue jacket, conducted by M.S.

Using 'course of [verb]-ing' doesn't sound standard to me. It's more natural to say, for instance, 'my sewing course', or 'my programming course', than 'my course of programming'.

Comment: Welcome to the ELL :-). A small suggestion: code formatting is a bit difficult to read (it strains the eyes) so on ELL it is preferred to use block quotes. I hope you don't mind that I've changed it in your answer.

Comment: No problem, I guess coming from stackoverflow it's natural for me to use code formatting. :)

Comment: @mk_hcc me too! +1 because I understand!